# MySQL SELECT email where field contains a value

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I would like to do a simple select - but the condition is a bit tricky for me (because I'm a SQL-beginner).

I got this table:

```
userid | email             | newsletters
     1 | test@example.com  | 1,2
     2 | test2@example.com | 1
```

Now I would like to get all email-addresses of users, which want to get newsletter "2".

This would be:

```
email | newsletters
test@example.com | 1,2
```

And of course: In another query all users, which are subscribing newsletter number 1:

Result:

```
email | newsletters
test@example.com | 1,2
test2@example.com | 1
```

What would be the correct sql-query?
I think this should be the right beginning, but I don't know which condition I have to use:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE newsletter CONDITION?
```

Could you please help me out? :-)

Comment: 1. See normalization

Comment: you should normalise the `newsletters` information so you dont have to do these hacks.. but something `like '%,2% or like '2,%'` should achieve the purpose

Comment: @amdixon - your proposition won't work if `newsletters` is just `'2'`

Comment: correct, you need a set of special conditions, this is just the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the work assuming number of newsletter can't be higher than `9`:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE newsletters LIKE '%2%'
```

If you'd like to have more of them then table normalization would be very helpful.

**EDIT:**
@sgeddes in comments has great proposition to make it working for any number of newsletters:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE concat(',',newsletters,',') LIKE '%,2,%'
```

Comment: Please read again my answer: "This will do the work assuming you have <10 newsletters"

Comment: This will incorrectly return records where newsletter contains '2' including , for example '1,12,15' .

Comment: @MichalKordas -- perhaps a better solution would be `where concat(',',newsletter,',') like '%,2,%'` -- that covers values greater than 9.  With that said, normalization is the best approach.

Comment: Okay, so it would be useful to create another table called subscriptions and set the rows: id, userid, newsletterid instead of writing this into the users-table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) if you really want to do this, but I think you need to redesign your table structure. Instead of storing the newsletters per user in the User table, you should create a bridge table between User and Newspaper like this:

```
User table
userid | email            
     1 | test@example.com 
     2 | test2@example.com

Newspaper table
paperid | name
      1 | the Sun
      2 | the Mirror

UserNewspaper Bridge table
userid | paperid     (represents, not part of table)
     1 | 1           (test@example.com receives the Sun)
     1 | 2           (test@example.com receives the Mirror)
     2 | 1           (test2@example.com receives the Sun)
```

To get all email-addresses of users that want paperid 2 you'd write this:

```
select a.email
from   User a,
       UserNewspaper b
where  a.userid = b.userid
and    b.paperid = 2
```

To get all email-addresses of users that want the Mirror you'd write this:

```
select a.email
from   User a,
       UserNewspaper b,
       Newspaper c
where  a.userid = b.userid
and    b.paperid = c.paperid
and    c.name = 'the Mirror'
```